# How to configure Interceptor in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I've made custom hibernate interceptor and I'm not sure how to configure it. I configured it like this in the hibernate.cfg.xml:

`<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor">bos.utils.CustomInterceptor</property>`

But it didn't executed yet no error shown. I saw this example:
`<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="bos.utils.CustomInterceptor"/>`

But this is in persistence.xml while I'm not using it.
BTW, my interceptor class under `bos.utils` package